# How to go to another page onClick in react

Tags: reactjs, navigation, react-router

I'm new to react and i'm trying to load another page when user clicks a button. I have used window.location but nothing happens when i click the button. How to fix this?

This where i have included my onClick

```
<div>
  <img className="menu_icons" src={myhome}/>
  <label className="menu_items" onClick={home}>Home</label>
</div>
```

Function written for onClick

```
function home(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = 'my-app/src/Containers/HomePage.jsx';
}
```

Comment: are you using `react router` ??

Comment: Did you find solution for the question you asked?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you really want to build a single app I'd suggest using [React Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router). Otherwise you could just use plain Javascript:

There are two main ways of doing depending on your desire you want to:

1. Style an `<a>` as your button
2. Use a `<button>` and redirect programatically

Since according to your question my assumption is that you're not building a single page app and using something along the lines of React router. And specifically mentioned use of `button` Below is a sample code

```
var Component = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() { return {query: ''} },
  queryChange: function(evt) {
    this.setState({query: evt.target.value});
  },
  handleSearch: function() {
    window.location.assign('/search/'+this.state.query+'/some-action');
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="component-wrapper">
        <input type="text" value={this.state.query} />
        <button onClick={this.handleSearch()} className="button">
          Search
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Mistakes I see according to your post

1. The function which uses `window.location` is not properly called in render method
2. You could use `window.location.assign()` method which helps to load new document
3. I doubt that `JSX` pages are rendered directly in browser level when you try to call them directly

Hope this would help, if not and you figure out an answer please share

Answer (score 6):

You need to bind the handler in the constructor of your component, otherwise React won't be able to find your `home` function.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.home = this.home.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the method using `this`, otherwise React does not find it.

```
<div>
  <img className="menu_icons" src={myhome}/>
  <label className="menu_items" onClick={this.home}>Home</label>
</div>
```

Comment: No it won't work if i include 'this.' I have tested with an alert. It shows up without 'this.'

Comment: Can you post what you have in full? I just need to see your component.

Comment: It won't work if you try to redirect to a `jsx` page which is not recognized by browsers. It would have to be an `html` page.